# What's a specific word for someone/something that you crave but could never have? Something along the lines of the usage "holy grail"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe a girl's yearning for a guy who'll never love her back. The sentence is "her skin was unsheathed to lure her *lover's* eyes". I want to remove the ambiguity in this sentence by replacing the word "lover," since that could imply that he loves her back.

Comment: To lure her "object's' eyes.  You use the tag single word, but use 'holy grail' as an example. confusing

Comment: I don't want to use 'holy grail',I need a single word alternative

Comment: But you are using 2 words as an example. Kindly consider allowing phrases or try out English Language Learners site.

Comment: "Her skin was unsheathed"? I'd work on that first. I am a highly educated native English speaker and that is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: I agree with @David. To me, it sounded a bit like she was being skinned alive.

Answer (score 4):

There are some one-word possibilities, none perfect.

> "her skin was unsheathed to lure her **unrequited's** eyes"

*Unrequited* by itself is pretty unambiguous, given that it is almost always used in conjunction with "love", but this isn't – strictly speaking – particularly grammatical.

> "her skin was unsheathed to lure her **beloved's** eyes"

*Beloved* fits grammatically, but like *flame* in [Wordster's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/472518/323865), it doesn't rule out that the feeling may be reciprocated. The same goes for *"her desired's"*, although that word implies reciprocation a bit less strongly (*desire/desired* carries a sense that the object has not – at least yet – been obtained), but is somewhat awkward to say.

> "her skin was unsheathed to lure her **idol's** eyes"

*Idol* is pretty good in terms of non-reciprocation, but makes the person into an object of veneration, not merely love.

> "her skin was unsheathed to lure her **infatuation's** eyes"

*Infatuation* is even closer but still – somewhat like *idol* – may imply a certain sense of obsession that mightn't be what you're looking for (and somewhat obviously this goes double or more for *"her obsession's"*).

> "her skin was unsheathed to lure her **inamorato's** eyes"

*Inamorato* is almost perfect (only establishes a one-way loving relationship, with no reciprocation implied), but is a really uncommon loan-word (from Italian, as it happens), and will make most readers pause to understand – or even look up – the word.

> "her skin was unsheathed to lure her **crush's** eyes"

*Crush* – I think – is the best option for this context, since (although it technically suffers from the same flaw as *flame*, *beloved*, *desired*, etc.) it is *usually* used in the sense that the object doesn't reciprocate the feeling (or may even be unaware of it).

The one weakness with *crush* is that it doesn't specifically imply an emotion as strong as mature love, but could be a more juvenile feeling, like what is usually called puppy-love.

Answer (score 0):

***[Flame](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/flame)***

> object of one's passionate love

Comment: I'm sorry,but I need a word that conveys the fact that this is an instance of unrequited love."Flame" could still suggest that he has feelings for her too.

Answer (score 0):

"her skin was unsheathed to lure the eyes of the object of her *limerence*"

> [limerence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limerence) in British English (ˈlɪmɪrəns) noun
>
> psychology:
>
> A state of mind resulting from romantic attraction,
>
> characterized by feelings of euphoria,
>
> the desire to have one's feelings reciprocated, etc.

The term came about in the late 70's:

> Limerence, a term coined by psychologist Dorothy Tennov in her 1979
> book Love and Limerence: The Experience of Being in Love

With the desire for, but without the necessity for any reciprocation for it to happen, it's [explained](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/david-sack-md/limerence_b_1627089.html?guccounter=1):

> Much to the dismay of diehard romantics, research suggests that
> limerence is the result of biochemical processes in the brain.
> Responding to cues from the hypothalamus, the pituitary gland releases
> norepinephrine, dopamine, phenylethylamine (a natural amphetamine),
> estrogen and testosterone. This chemical cocktail produces the
> euphoria of new love and begins to normalize as the attachment
> hormones (vasopressin and oxytocin) kick in.

Comment: Nice, but you've changed the stucture of the sentence to include "object of" which violates the "one word" requirement. "Desire" would have the same problem, except that "object of desire" can be phrased as "desired", similar to"beloved".

Comment: @Michael R. Bernstein Quite true, in the strictest sense. I see that I've added to the lack of precision. I'd hesitated to say it - but there may be no answer that fits exactly. Your "inamorato" may be best. +1